# Back key infinitely loops back to same activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back, android-lifecycle

I am programming an Android application and have a curious issue.

My application has a LoginActivity that defines the filter for launch events.
As soon as login is complete, it starts the "Home" activity using `startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class))` and stops the LoginActivity using `finish()`.

The HomeActivity is a simple dashboard with notifications, overriding `onCreate` and `onStart`. Also it updates the some content icons using an AsyncThread.

The problem is this: If I hit the Home-Button to exit my app and then use the "recent" menu (holdpress the Android-Home Button) to reopen it, the back-key is 'broken' in my app: Pressing it will not finish the HomeActivity, but instead loop back to the same activity:

Meaning ... HomeActivity <- HomeActivity <- HomeActivity <- HomeActivity ...

I have not used any hacks to override the backstack or back key behaviour.
Anyone got a clue what the cause of this may be?

TIA, Patrick

Comment: What did you do in onStart() ?

Comment: onStart basically triggers the reloading of data (starting a new AsyncTask if one is not already running).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your login activity detects that login is complete and sends you immediately back to your home activity. That should be visible from the log (`ActivityManager, START intent ...`)

In that case it may be a good idea to play with the backstack

Comment: Ah, stupidstupid. You are right - it does do that of course. Thus this is why it goes back to the HomeActivity.

Comment: And there lies the problem - the backstack was not manipulated to remove said activity, when it was restarted in the "loggedOn" case. Ah, never program in the night ^^ Thank you!